# What are the rules of Coq implicit types deduction in Inductive definitions?

Tags: coq

Consider this type that has `X` as an implicit type.

```
Inductive list' {X:Type} : Type :=
  | nil'
  | cons' (x : X) (l : list').
```

Coq deduced that type of the second argument of `cons'` is `@list' A`:

```
Fail Check cons' a (cons' b nil'). (* "cons' b nil'" expected to have type "@list' A"*)
```

But how was this type deduced unambiguously?
We can create another type:

```
Inductive list'' {X:Type} : Type :=
  | nil''
  | cons'' (x : X) (l : @list'' B).

Check cons'' a (cons'' b nil'').
```

It shows that `l` could also be `@list' B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, Coq inferred the type of `cons'` to be `forall {X}, X -> @list' X -> @list' X`. Then when you write `cons a`, Coq works out that you must be building a `@list' A`, and fills in `X` with `A`, thus constraining the second argument to be again of type `@list' A`.

However, the choice of `X` over some other type is not the only possible choice, as you noticed. In your second example, `cons''` gets type `forall {X}, X -> @list'' B -> @list'' X`. However, when it is left unspecified, most people most of the time intend their parameters (things on the left side of the colon) to be *uniform*, that is, the same in the arguments as in the conclusion, which *heuristic* leads to the choice of `X` here. In general, Coq doesn't worry too much about making sure it's solutions are unique for things the user left unspecified.

In recent enough versions of Coq, you can use the option [Uniform Inductive Parameters](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.12/refman/language/core/inductive.html#coq:flag.uniform-inductive-parameters) to specify that all parameters are uniform, or use a `|` to separate the uniform from the non-uniform parameters. In the case of lists, that would look like

```
Inductive list' (X:Type) | : Type :=
  | nil'
  | cons' (x : X) (l : list').
```

Note that with the `|`, in the declaration of constructors `list'` has type `Type`, while without the `|`, `list'` has type `Type -> Type`, and there is a constraint that the conclusion of the constructor has to be `list X` (while the arguments can use `list other_type` freely).